# Randomizing String in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to be able to add words to my Hangman game so my previous arrays was created like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
String[] word = {"iran","japan","canada","america","malaysia"};
randomword = word[random.nextInt(word.length)];
```

The problem is that this array is fixed size, so I tried using `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
word.add("iran");
word.add("japan");
word.add("canada");
Random random = new Random();
randomword = word[random.nextInt(word.length)];
```

but it didn't work, the error is (array required, but arrayList found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements is an `ArrayList` are retrieved using the `get(index)` method, and the `size()` method is used instead of `length`.

change

```
randomword = word[random.nextInt(word.length)];
```

to

```
randomword = word.get(random.nextInt(word.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks that was quick :D

Answer (score 3):

`randomword = word[random.nextInt(word.length)];` there is no syntax in java that allows you to use index with `ArrayList` , use `get()` instead.